# Converting region $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y) dydx$ from rectangular form to polar form

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

How can I convert the region in

$$
\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y) dydx
$$

(which is basically a right triangle contained in the first quadrant) to a polar form? Im sure that

$$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$$

but what should one do about the radius range?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you drawn the region on a piece of paper and tried to find $r$ as a function of $\theta$? It's elementary trigonometry.

Comment: I think that $0<r<2\sqrt 2$ because the maximum distance from the origin of the line $y=x$, give that $x<=2$ is $2\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Arthur yes I did and I found 2/cos(theta). Is that correct? I understand that it is basic trigonometry but lets say that the region is a triangle between points (0,0), (1,1) and (-1,1). Does that transition mean that I should use two integrals? Or 1/sin(theta) can handle the whole interval?

Comment: @bru1987 No, you're correct. The limits should be $\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{2/\cos \theta}drd\theta$. Don't forget that the integrand should change slightly to reflect your variable substitution.

Comment: @Arthur yes by using r dr dtheta, thats true. Ok thank you Arthur, best regards.